# How to check if ground plane (vuforia) is supported in run time?

Tags: unity-game-engine, vuforia

I need to check if my device is compatible with ground plane in runtime and if it isn't, change it for other AR component.

Comment: What attempts have you made to solve your issue? It is expected from Askers to show research effort.

Comment: I've looked everywhere, including unity and vuforia forums and I have not found anything. There are questions regarding the subject but no answers so far. Then, I have tried to write a list with all compatible devices but is kind of tricky having to put by hand all new devices in case new ones appear

Comment: You know you can add a `Ground plane` object and an `Image target` in the same scene. If the device does not support `Ground plane` it will give an error at start.

Comment: In my case, it doesn't give me any error, simply, the camera appears.

Comment: If you run it in play mode in Unity you will see that it does give an error. It also does it on your device, however you don't see the error because you have not logged your app's output.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We needed the same in our project. We used **[this](https://gist.github.com/vad710/e9047eb834648a42cc6e5f9b16806bc7)** cause the official API seems to be still buggy.